# Can't make windows 7 to go bootable

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-to-go

I am trying to create a bootable Windows 7 To Go USB drive (It is possible, as looking in the sources folder it has install.wim). I followed this [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/196817/how-to-create-a-windows-to-go-usb-drive-without-the-enterprise-edition/) and I simply had to take out `/f ALL` as that command doesn't exist on windows 7's bcdboot.

So after trying the edited command, `bcdboot X:\Windows /s X:` (where X is my drive) it gave me the message `Failed to attempt copying boot files`. I have looked everywhere else and cannot seem to find any information to fix this.

Comment: The command failed.  What errors did you receive?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you trying to make a bootable installation media or to fix a non-bootable installation? UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: Trying to fix a non-bootable installation, I got the error saying failiure when attempting to copy boot files

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isn't enough diagnostic information for an answer, and the problem was solved so no answer is needed.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it!!!

I just tried it on a different computer and it worked!

I used the same command as well

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  In 1 1/2 days, you will be able to accept your own answer, which will signify that the problem has been solved.